# Churn State meaning in LACP bonding

Tags: linux, networking, lacp

What does `Actor Churn State` and `Partner Churn State` means about an slave interface in `/proc/net/bonding/bond0` and what are the possible values for it and what do they mean?

Answer (score 3):

In order to setup Link Aggregation (LAG) each Ethernet link exchanges LACPDUs (Link Aggregation Control Protocol Data Units) with directly connected device that also implement LACP. [[Summary](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/layer-2-lacp-security-understanding.html)] [[Details](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100086560)]

The system is collecting information from the received PDUs on each participating link to find possible aggregations. If a received PDU changes the knowledge (LACP state information) about any of the links, this link will inform its peer about the changed state information. This goes on until there is a consensus about the role of each link in the aggregation. [[LACP state information](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/command-summary/show-lacp-interfaces.html#show-lacp-interfaces-table)] [[More details](https://ieee802.org/3/ad/public/nov98/jeffree_3_1198.pdf)]

Churn in this context means the failure of a link to reach a consensus with its peer in a reasonable time.

**Churn State shows if the Link is either waiting (monitoring) for additional PDUs to reach consensus, the result was a churn (churned) or the link is in sync (none).**

Different Churn Count for Actor and Partner indicate that one end of the link was able to reach synchronous state and the other end did not.

However, the current [IEEE 802.1AX-2014](https://1.ieee802.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/802-1AX-Rev-d1-0.pdf) standard which superseded 802.1ad removed the Churn machines from the protocol.

> The Churn machines have been removed. They were a nice idea but don’t do much or work as originally intended. [[details](https://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/docs2018/ax-seaman-lacp-suggestions-0118-02.pdf)]